# JS Break out of function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I've got a method that looks like this:

```
return AddedSoftware (software) {
    this.softwares.map(function(soft) {
        if(soft.id == software) {
            return software.name;
        }
    })
}
```

So how could I break and return when `soft.id == software` now it loops through the entire `softwares` before it returns!

Comment: The `.map()` function is the wrong choice; `.find()` is probably what you want, of not a simple `for` loop.

Comment: use native for loop to the `.map` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would use [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead

```
return function AddedSoftware (software) {
    let res = this.softwares.find(soft => soft.id == software);
    // return the software's name if there's a match, or undefined
    return res ? res.name : res;
}
```

This will give you the first object matching your condition. You can then get `software.name` from that object.

Excerpt from the docs:

> The find() method returns a value of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise undefined is returned.

Comment: The OP's function was trying to return the "name" property of the found item.

Comment: Edited the answer @Pointy

Comment: Thanks - I almost did it myself but I'm afraid people would consider that rude.

Comment: Feel free to improve my answers everytime :D @Pointy

Comment: Great answer! But in IE 11 I receive: ```[Vue warn]: Error when evaluating expression "addedSoftware(software)": TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'find'```

Comment: IE doesn't support find() (just like most ecmascript2015). You can include the polyfill you'll find on the documentation page I linked to to make it work @Jamie